# Is The Nether randomly generated?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just created my first portal to The Nether.

Now I'm justing wondering if The Nether is always same for everybody or is it also randomly generated as the "real world"?

Comment: What gave you the idea it could be non-random?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The nether is just a special [Biome](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biomes), and is generated the same way as any other Biome (except only in the Nether of course). According to the wiki, occasionally nether biomes will spawn in the overworld!

It was a separate map theme in Indev mode (albeit with dirt/sand instead of netherack/soul sand), and as such had a different algorithm for generating the terrain.

So yes, the Nether **is randomly generated**, it will be different for different seeds (it uses the same seed to generate terrain as the overworld). And even among worlds with the same seed, the location where a new destination nether portal spawns is randomized separately.

Comment: However, it uses completely different oscillator patterns than the overworld. Just a note.

Comment: I've never seen a nether biome in the overworld, on any version. What version was this? (sorry for possible necropost, just curious)

Answer (score 3):

It is generated in the same way as the main world (using the seed). This means it will be different for every world.

If you delete the Nether from the map files and recreate it by taking another portal you will be in exactly the same nether as you were first in.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a biome like the others (Except that it only can be in a special world, as the End), **yes**.

It is generated with the same seed as the overworld biomes, that you can see using the *F3* menu. You can set it manually under the advanced menu before creating the world. Otherwise, it's randomly generated.