# How do level seeds work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I see minecraft seeds listed, and I started trying some of my own.

I have noticed using the same seed produces very similar styles of maps, i.e. start in a specific biome, very high mountains etc, but do they reproduce the maps exactly and you just spawn in the same place, or are they just a very specific set of rules for the area you first spawn?

If I have two maps of the same seed, and I walk 1000 blocks north, will the maps be identical/similar or totally random after the first spawn area?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Computers are deterministic machines, incapable as such of non-deterministic (= random) behavior. What they *can* do is use complex math to simulate random behavior: this gives pseudo-random numbers.

For example, when I run Python 3 for Windows 7 I get:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(1) #I set the seed to a fixed value...
>>> random.random() #and ask for 3 "random" numbers
0.13436424411240122
>>> random.random()
0.8474337369372327
>>> random.random()
0.763774618976614
```

I then connect to an Ubuntu 11.04 machine with Python 2, and get:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(1) #I set again the seed to the previous fixed value
>>> random.random() #and ask again for 3 "random" numbers
0.13436424411240122
>>> random.random() #...doesn't look very random, does it?
0.8474337369372327
>>> random.random()
0.763774618976614
```

So, the *same* pseudo-random engine will always give the *same* numbers in the *same* order. This doesn't imply the game actually uses the same numbers in the same way, however, as [yx_](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3917/yx) insightfully [thought](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/22476/1). However, the game could be written in a way to ensure this; for example, one could derive from each seed (say, "foo") a different seed per each block (say, "foo@1@2" to determine the chunk 1,2). How can we tell how this is done?

**There's only one way to know!**

I used the seed "[Mersenne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister)" to create two worlds, a world A and a world B.

In world A I spawned in world A at (262.5, -280.5); I attempted to move in the direction I spawned in as straight as possible for 500 units, then back for a thousand. This is what I got.

[image: Mersenne A map.]

In world B I spawned in (+259.5, -276,5), just to make things easier. I attempted to move in the direction *opposite* to the one I spawned in for 500 units, then back for a thousand; in short, I travelled back and forth on the same 1.5 km, just in a different order. This is what I got.

[image: Mersenne B map. Mostly identical.]

(Keep in mind that, as I explored, I removed blocks here and there for navigational purposes.)

This results are shockingly identical. I say shockingly because I certainly had the impression the two worlds were quite similar... but not quite the same.

Indeed, if we zoom on the spawn point, we can see some differences... but it is mainly only about trees. The underground area is not pictured, and identical.

[image: Spawn point, zoomed.]

In short: the seed system is *almost* perfect and the same seed will give you two worlds that are *almost* identical to each other. I haven't tried the nether, but I have no reason to believe it would behave differently.

Comment: The only way the trees can be placed differently is if the software uses another, independent seed (the time from the system clock is a very common one) to decide on tree placement which would explain the minor differences.

Comment: The strangest thing by far is how *most* of the trees seem to be identical!

Comment: @rmx: The other possibility is that the program isn't deterministic - in particular, if multiple threads read off of the same random number generator, variation from run to run could essentially swap random numbers around from one place to another.

Comment: @Jefromi Minecraft is (currently) [single-threaded](http://www.overclock.net/pc-games/1011677-minecraft-putting-lot-stress-only-one.html).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Huh, well then I am very curious where these differences came from!

Comment: @Jefromi Probably the tree-placement code is dependent on biome data (which would be deterministic with the same seed) but has a separate random algorithm that isn't directly using the seed. If the biome data says a chunk needs 4 trees, there are only so many ways even a random algorithm can place those in a 16x16 block area. If the algorithm prunes "bad" placements, it will have even less variation.

Comment: Keep in mind that trees may straddle a chunk boundary (and other structures such as caves may cross many chunks). I suspect that the difference results from the order in which chunks are generated.

Answer (score 4):

The [seed in Minecraft](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Random_seed) is used as a [random seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed), i.e. it causes the terrain generator to produce *random* terrain, but in a *repeatable* way. Using the same seed will result in **identical** terrain, for as far as you walk, right down to the flowers, and [the nether](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22230/is-the-nether-randomly-generated).

Your [spawn point may not be identical](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20895/do-you-always-spawn-on-sand), however.

There are around 18 quintillion (18,000,000,000,000,000,000) different possible seeds.

Comment: I think badp's post proves it's not quite down to the flowers, interestingly enough.

Comment: @Shinrai Yes, agreed. Clearly trees are added according to some random generation that's separate to the seed, I wonder if flowers are the same?

Comment: I had the same thought, and my hunch would be 'probably'.  Worth investigating, probably...

Answer (score 2):

The seeds for a map in minecraft is used inside a [Pseudo Random Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

> A pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) is an algorithm for generating a sequence of numbers that approximates the properties of random numbers. The sequence is not truly random in that it is completely determined by a relatively small set of initial values, called the PRNG's state.

Comment: Incorrect, the worlds will be identical. Chunks are not random, and do not 'consume' elements of the hash chain, otherwise the terrain would not be 'continuous'.

Comment: @fredley Not necessarily; the terrain _can_ (and likely, is) smoothed after being randomly generated.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the world building is deterministic.  https://twitter.com/jeb_/status/40351239543721984 (is smoothing non-deterministic?)

Comment: @Matthew Read - smoothing would only be stochastic (a much cooler way to say 'random') if it used a random number somewhere in the subroutine.

Comment: That was what I meant, yes.