# If I upload a seed, will my creations be saved on it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am uploading a world, and if I upload it as a seed, will my user-made creations still be saved on the seed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do level seeds work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22474/how-do-level-seeds-work)

Comment: @pppery The duplicate doesn't answer this question. It can be gleaned from the answer, but that's no reason to close them as duplicates, right?

Answer (score 26):

No, the seed is only used for the first generation of the world. They will see the world as it first appeared to you.