# Logic of seed on Minecraft for world map creation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Based on response and the experience of @badp on that question: [How do level seeds work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22474/how-do-level-seeds-work)

And also based on the seeds displayed after choosing default "worlds" in the GUI and on the seeds people share in internet;

**Does seed number have any known logic that we can manipulate it to create specific world maps?**

This question is different from the referenced one because it is the extension of @badp experiment in the answer of that question: the same seed generate the same world map in terms of biome and relief, ignoring whole sort of variants, like position of trees, different buildings etc.

I expect something like relationship of decimal or binary number with the presence of biomes and relief, their position in the world and default worlds' list...

Comment: In my opinion, no. You need to know the right sequence of randomly generated numbers that can create the desired world map, and then "reverse engineer" that to obtain the generator number of that sequence. I don't say it's impossibile, it will be just too hard to find out.